# R highchart parallel coordinates

Tags: r, parallel-coordinates, r-highcharter

Is it possible to plot a highchart parallel coordinates in R using highcharter library?
Something like - https://www.highcharts.com/demo/parallel-coordinates

From highcharts documentation about parallelCoordinates option - "This feature requires modules/parallel-coordinates.js".
I download one from https://code.highcharts.com/modules/parallel-coordinates.js
but how can I use it?
Need minimal working example.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi, the parallel coordinates comes with the recent version of highcarts (v6) so will take about 1 week yo have this plugin in the highcharter development version

Comment: I'm looking forward to it! Thank you for providing this information!